# Transaction in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

i open one transaction and insert a row into table and close the ssms and reopen and check table but uncommitted transaction were in the resultset why this happen please tell me

Comment: what's the output you are getting?  is DATETIME an actual  DATETIME field type?  What do you get if you do select distinct * from logs_currentmonth WHERE DATETIME>='01-OCT-2016'  ??  What range of dates do you get?  Is it getting unexpected data?

Comment: Capslock is a great way to get people to ignore your question

Comment: @HoneyBadger  - which caps?  SQL is often itself written very much in caps as a standard - do you mean the question title itself?  I think SQL does look ugly in CAPS - but you do get used to it, and it can start to look odd in lower case.

Comment: @andrew deighton sir i am getting same same kind of result set and the date column is problem date column datatype is DATETIME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is data for some *other* month that has a 28th.  I would recommend:

```
select cast([datetime] as date), count(*)
from (select distinct cm.*
      from logs_currentmonth cm
     ) cm
where [datetime] >= '2016-10-01'
group by cast([datetime] as date)
order by cast([datetime] as date);
```

If you don't need the `select distinct`, then don't use it!  It just slows down the query.

Comment: i am mentitioning  date in where clause so how it possible to take date from another month

Comment: try the select distinct * from logs_currentmonth WHERE DATETIME>='01-OCT-2016'  separately to see if it returns unexpected data,

Comment: @ARJUN . . . Run this query and see where the data comes from.